# getting `ClientConfigurationError: empty_url_error: URL was empty or null` when trying to pass headers via axiosinstance

Tags: javascript, axios

Iam using a react appliation. I need to pass Bearer key in headers for axios call.

Iam using `@azure-msal` for authentication.

When trying to call the created `axiosInstance`., getting `ClientConfigurationError: empty_url_error: URL was empty or null. at ClientConfigurationError.AuthError [as constructor]` error.

Not sure what iam missing. Can you help me.. Below is the code Iam using

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
const getAxiosInstance = () => {
  const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    },
  };
  const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
  console.log("Msal account new",account);
  const scopes = ["openid", "profile", process.env.REACT_APP_OAUTH_SCOPE_URL];
  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes,
      account,
    });
    return response.accessToken;
  };
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL_PROJECT,
  });
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    const token = await getAccessToken();
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  });
  return axiosInstance;
};
export default getAxiosInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but one reason that msal-browser will throw that error code is if the authority is empty.

There may be a problem with your build process and the env variables are not being populated correctly.  You should check this by inspecting the code directly in your browser and if they aren't populated then you know that the problem is with the build process.